# Excel VBA Charting: How to have positive and negative values above 0 but red green colors?

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I believe there is a little trick that I can't figure out.

Excel VBA Charting: How to have positive and negative values above 0 but red green colors?

I need to easy compare negative positive values.

Thanks.

Comment: It's not very clear what you want to do here.  You may need to separate out your positive and negative values into two different series, and change the sign on your negative values.  Then plot both sets on the same plot.

Comment: I also need this, did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Select chart Axis (Y/X). Select Format Selection on Format tab. Find "Number" on the right box. Change Category to Number and select/change Negative Number box to red value.

Hope this help.

Comment: For Axis yes, I have try it.

Comment: If you mean it is for data series bar, I think you need to try the tricks in this link: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2218-excel-chart-negative-values-different-color.html but it still cannot change negative number to positive.

Comment: yea ..the trick is to have them both in the same side (positive) with highlighting negative values by red.